# Create View Box in MarkLogic 8 Admin Console

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

How do I bring up the create view box in the Marklogic 8 admin console? I did it once by luck when putting in some element range indexes but haven't been able to bring it back up again

Answer (score 2):

There's not a way to create a view through the admin console. You can define all of your range indexes via the admin console, but creating SQL views is done either through POST statements as illustrated in
[the SQL Data Modeling Guide](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/creating-views#id_40868), or it's done through qconsole using the [view:view XQuery API in qconsole](https://docs.marklogic.com/view:views).

Answer (score 1):

Ahh...the UI referred to in the original question is actually part of the (deprecated) Information Studio. The link to get to it is in the Configuration Manager UI- the cog icon to the right of the databases.

The best ways to create views are what were described in the answer above.